# With SSD's and in memory tables, does a snowflake schema become preferred over a star?

Tags: database-design

With SSD's being very fast (reducing the overhead of joins), while more expensive (increasing the cost of redundancy due to de-normalization), along-with a focus on in memory tables (again reducing the costs of joins), are there situations where snowflake schemas are now preferred over star schemas?

AFAIK snowflake schemas are rarely used in production quality code now